# Why does sorting work with 'less than' comparison but not with 'less or equal'?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, stl

I am trying to sort a `vector<vector<int>>` array using sort as follows:

```
sort(ed.begin(),ed.end(),[](vector<int> a,vector<int> b){return a[2]<=b[2];}
```

Here ed is my array( of arrays ) and each element in this array is of size 3. So I am kinda sorting triplets with respect to last element. But this gives a segmentation fault at this very line of code. I tried to research on this and what I could find is something about strict weak ordering required in comparison function. So I then changed the sort statement as follows:

```
sort(ed.begin(),ed.end(),[](vector<int> a,vector<int> b){return a[2]<b[2];})
```

Basically I just removed the equality sign from the comparison function. And this worked. **So I want to know why this works and the previous one does not.**

Just to let you know the complete picture, I am trying to implement kruskal's algorithm and "ed" is an array of edges. Each edge is a triplet `<from,to,weight>`.

Comment: You need to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, but my best guess is that not all elements of the array have at least 3 elements

Comment: It's just that `std::sort` needs a sorter which follows the strict weak ordering rule. That's all.

Comment: Please take those vectors a and b by const reference.